# Publish NuGet with multiple targets, where one is vNext stuff, version as stable or unstable?

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I have a NuGet, currently `v2.0.0`. It is a portable class library (PCL) supporting .Net4.0+ and WP, Win8, Silverlight (oh-yeah)..., but not `vNext` (dotnet profile as in universal and aspnetcore50).

Now I have fixed a separate PCL for `vNext`, that targets the `dotnet` profile (universal app for win 10, net46, aspnetcore50).

So the nupkg contains `myproj.vDinasour.dll` and `myproj.vNext.dll`. Hence if you install in pre `vNext` you get `myproj.vDinasour.dll` if in `vNext` you get `myproj.vNext.dll`.

I bumped to `v3.0.0` from `v2.0.0`, but should I instead bump to `v3.0.0-pre1` or maybe put out two nupkgs?